# Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component: typeof Rec...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]

Tags: angular

This error is popping out when i write routes for my application

```
Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component: typeof Rec...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]
```

My routes file is

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {RecipesComponent} from './recipes/recipes.component';
import {ShoppingListComponent} from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import {recipe_routing} from "./recipes/recipe.routes";

const approutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent, children: recipe_routing},
  {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(approutes);
```

what mistakes have i done in this file that it isnt working.It says that approutes(the constant that i have assigned) is the one that is not working.

recipe routing

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {RecipeStartComponent} from "./recipe-start.component";
import {RecipeEditComponent} from "./recipe-edit/recipe-edit.component";
import {RecipeDetailComponent} from "./recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component";

export const recipe_routing: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: RecipeStartComponent},
  {path: 'new', component: RecipeEditComponent},
  {path: ':id', component: RecipeDetailComponent},
  {path: ':id/edit', component: RecipeEditComponent}
];
```

This is the recipe routing

i did not write the `export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(approutes);`since this is just a children route.

Comment: try like this `const approutes: Routes[] = [...]`

Comment: Can you post your `recipe_routing`? The problem most likely lies there

Comment: I have included it and Maximus its not working that way, an error saying Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'. pops up

Comment: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187168/2545680) and show your full code

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187168/2545680) help?

Answer (score 2):

> i did not write the export const routing =
>   RouterModule.forRoot(approutes);since this **is just a children route**.

For child routes you should use `forChild()` method like this:

```
const approutes: Routes[] = [...]

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(approutes)

...

@NgModule({
   imports: [routing]
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't export the constant in a single statement. ie. `export const approutes` Try that way perhaps.
RouterModule.forRoot(approutes) should be in the app-module.ts in the @ngModule inside the imports:[]